# Using Regex to determine if string contains a repeated sequence of a particular substring with comma separators and nothing else

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to find if a string contains a repeated sequence of a known substring (with comma separators) and nothing else and return true if this is the case; otherwise false. For example: the substring is "0,8"

String A: "0,8,0,8,0,8,0,8" returns true
String B: "0,8,0,8,1,0,8,0" returns false because of '1'

I tried using the C# string functions Contains but it does not suit my requirements. I am totally new to regular expression but I feel it should be powerful enough to do this. What RegEx should I use to do this?

Comment: Why not just a simple `String.Split`?

Comment: Actually, "0,8,0,8..." is not made up of _just_ "0,8" substrings. There are commas in between. So, just checking that it is made up of substrings of "0,8" should actually return `false`.

Comment: Yes! I was wrong with the examples. I didn't put enough thought into it and totally ignored the extra commas. The problem now becomes more complicated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern for a string containing nothing but a repeated number of a given substring (possibly zero of them, resulting in an empty string) is `\A(?:substring goes here)*\z`.   The `\A` matches the beginning of the string, the `\z` the end of the string, and the `(?:...)*` matches 0 or more copies of anything matching the thing between the colon and the close parenthesis.

But your string doesn't actually match `\A(?:0,8)*\z`, because of the extra commas; an example that would match is "0,80,80,80,8". You need to account for the commas explicitly with something like `\A0,8(?:,0,8)*\z`.

You can build such a thing in C# thus:

```
string OkSubstring = "0,8";
string aOk = "0,8,0,8,0,8,0,8";
string bOK = "0,8,0,8,1,0,8,0";

Regex OkRegex = new Regex( @"\A" + OkSubstring + "(?:," + OkSubstring + @")*\z" );
OkRegex.isMatch(aOK);  // True
OkRegex.isMatch(bOK);  // False
```

That hard-codes the comma-delimiter; you could make it more general.  Or maybe you just need the literal regex.  Either way, that's the pattern you need.

**EDIT** Changed the anchors per Mike Samuel's suggestion.

Comment: @MikeSamuel - Good point; I'm too used to thinking in terms of lines.  Corrected!